# SQL Query for retrieving items and their data stored as key value pairs

Tags: mysql, one-to-many, key-value

I'm setting up a system to store different types of items that can have different data types associated with them but I'm unsure how I should query the database to return items and all of their data.

I am using mysql.

This is the model of the tables that I'm using.

[image]

Items have an associated record ID (rID) and the records table stores key-value pairs containing the data (datatype as key, value as value).

Ideally I would be able to query the database for items where a certain record's value is equal to x and it would return a single row for each item with a field for each data type's value and its data type ID (I'm not sure whether this is possible or not though).

As an added constraint, new item types and data types may be added at any time so a query allows for this would make things much easier.

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retrieving a row, with data from key-value pair table in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164350/retrieving-a-row-with-data-from-key-value-pair-table-in-mysql)

Comment: Hi Jmail, thanks for the response.  That works but I'm unsure how efficient it would be if it had 50 joins for 50 different datatypes, and also how it would find the number of datatypes it needed join each time?  Thanks again, Tomm