# MySQL query transform

Tags: mysql

I am getting this output in mysql query.(which has key value pairs)

```
-id NAME            VALUE
--1 customerName    Narendra
--1 customerCountry India
```

How we can convert this to (single line)

```
id customerName  country
1   Narendra        India
```

Comment: have a look there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table

Comment: `SELECT Id,GROUP_CONCAT(VALUE ORDER BY NAME DESC) FROM t GROUP BY Id`

Comment: @Mihai please note that with `GROUP_CONCAT` the values are in the same field in the resultset, e.g. you need a separator and process the result later on.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164350/retrieving-a-row-with-data-from-key-value-pair-table-in-mysql

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164350/retrieving-a-row-with-data-from-key-value-pair-table-in-mysql